# Excel VBA cell upper/lower case depending other cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code to loop through an excel sheet and changing the text (in column B) to uppercase/lowercase, depending on the value of cell in column N on the same row.

Macros purpose:
loop through cells in column B starting at row 2 and changing the string from upper to lowercase or vice versa, depending on the value of the cell in column N (lowercase if value = 5, other cases text should be uppercase)

Code I've got so far:

```
Sub CAPS()
'
' CAPS Macro
'
Dim Rang As Integer
Dim j As Integer


j = 2
    For Each N In Source.Range("N2:N10000")   ' Do 10000 rows
        Rang = Cells(j, 14)
        If Rang = 5 Then
           Cells(j, 2).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Value = LCase$(ActiveCell.Text)
            Else
            ActiveCell.Value = UCase$(ActiveCell.Text)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next N


End Sub
```

I'm a little bit stuck in the looping part, not really a clue how to fix the error(s) in the current code.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are the errors in the current code? One obvious thing is that you use `N` and `j`, which at all times have the same value, so I suggest you replace all `j`with `N`

Comment: Also rewrite your `FOR EACH...` to `FOR N is 2 to 10000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CAPS()
'
' CAPS Macro
'
Dim N as long  'use long here as integer is limite to a 32b character

For N Is 2 to 10000   ' Do 10000 rows
   If Cells(N, 14) = 5 Then
       Cells(N, 2) = LCase(Cells(N,2)
   Else
       Cells(N, 2) = UCase(Cells(N,2)
   EndIf     
Next N

End Sub
```

This should do the trick, untested though.

You currently have a fixed number of rows you want to test. To optimize your code you could first check how many rows are filled with data. To do so you can use:

`DIM lastrow as long`
`lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

And then make the loop with `For N Is 2 to lastrow`

Also it is good practice to explicitly reference your worksheets, as this prevents undesired results. For example you click on another worksheet whilst the code is running it will continue formatting on that sheet. To do so declare a variable as your worksheet:

`DIM ws as worksheet`

And set a value to your variable, in this case Sheet1.

`Set ws as ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Now every time you reference a `Cells()`, you explicitly say on what sheet that has to be by adding `ws.` in front of it like such: `ws.Cells()`

To summarize all that into your code:

```
Sub CAPS()
'
' CAPS Macro
'

Dim N as long  'use long here as integer is limite to a 32b character
Dim lastrow as long
Dim ws as worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the code to run on Sheet 1 of your current workbook.
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For N Is 2 to lastrow   ' Do all rows that have data in column B
   If ws.Cells(N, 14) = 5 Then
       ws.Cells(N, 2) = LCase(ws.Cells(N,2)
   Else
       ws.Cells(N, 2) = UCase(ws.Cells(N,2)
   EndIf     
Next N

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try processing in an array,

```
Sub CAPS()
'
' CAPS Macro
'
    Dim arr As variant, j As Integer

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        arr = .range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "B").end(xlup).offset(0, 12)).value2
        for j= lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1)
            if arr(j, 13) = 5 then
                arr(j, 1) = lcase(arr(j, 1))
            else
                arr(j, 1) = ucase(arr(j, 1))
            end if
        next j
        redim preserve arr(lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1), 1 to 1)
        .cells(2, "B").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr
    end with

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub CAPS()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")   'Sheet where you have to change the letter case
lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    Select Case ws.Cells(i, "N")
        Case 5
            ws.Cells(i, "B") = LCase(ws.Cells(i, "B"))
        Case Else
            ws.Cells(i, "B") = UCase(ws.Cells(i, "B"))
    End Select
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using for each loop with Range:

```
Sub UCaseLCase()

  Dim rng, cell As Range

  Dim Test As Integer
  Test = 5
  Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(10000, 14))

  For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value = Test Then
        cell.Offset(0, -12) = LCase(cell.Offset(0, -12))
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, -12) = UCase(cell.Offset(0, -12))
    End If
  Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said in your question *starting at row 2* but it's easier just going from last row until row 2.

Hope this can help or at least, learn something new about Loops :)

```
Sub CAPS()
Dim j As Integer

For j = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Range("N" & j).Value = 5 Then
        'uppercase
        Range("B" & j).Value = UCase(Range("B" & j).Value)
    Else
        'lowercase
        Range("B" & j).Value = LCase(Range("B" & j).Value)
    End If
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Why is it easier to go from bottom to top in this case? It is easier in the case of deleting rows, to prevent you miss rows, but there is no real need for reversing the step in this case.

Comment: Yep, you are right. I guess I'm used to this loops and type less code lines.